# Identity server 4 error on https on production

Tags: identityserver4

I have identity server 4 configured and deployed using https.
But I keep getting this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {fd73cc47-5d25-4d3b-a5cf-14b193aafc64} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
info: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
Hosting environment: Production
```

Here is my configuration

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore(Configuration["signingCredentialCertificateThumbPrint"]))
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddRiqueraUserStore();

services.AddAuthentication();
```

I would appreciate any help with this.